# DataTableExtensions.AsEnumerable() throws InvalidCastException

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-dataset

I'm using the DataTableExtensions.AsEnumerable method to create a List . The following code is throwing an InvalidCastException:

```
SaleDiscount = (i.Field<decimal>("OnSalePercentAdjustment") * i.Field<decimal>("Price")),
```

I don't have to use LINQ, With a few more keystrokes I can work through the data table with a foreach loop:

```
i.Price = Convert.ToDecimal(row["Price"]);
var saleDiscount = Convert.ToDecimal(row["SaleDiscount "]);
i.SalePrice = i.Price - (i.Price * saleDiscount );
i.SaleDiscount = i.Price - i.SalePrice;
```

Just curious, how can I fix the LINQ? And wondering whether using LINQ here delivers any advantages over some saved keystrokes.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that one of the columns does not have type of `decimal`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get cast exceptions in one case and no exceptions in the other because `Convert.ToDecimal` is a lot more lenient than a simple cast. Cast exception indicates that the underlying field is *not* a `decimal`, but it has a type that can be easily converted to `decimal`.

To use `Convert.ToDecimal` inside LINQ query, change your code as follows:

```
SaleDiscount = (
           Convert.ToDecimal(i.Field<object>("OnSalePercentAdjustment")) *
           Convert.ToDecimal(i.Field<object>("Price"))),
```

Alternatively, you could figure out the correct type, use `Field<correct-type>(...)` to read it, and then do the cast to `decimal`.

Comment: Both you and Marcin nailed it. Checking this as the answer because you taught me some new LINQ. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's because one of your columns is not `decimal`.

It may be e.g. `int`, and even it's still numeric, and you can cast `int` to `decimal`, because `.Field<T>` logic looks like that:

```
return (T)((object)value);
```

and because you can only unbox value into the same they were boxed from:

```
int value = 3;
object boxedValue = value;

// works fine
int unboxedValue = (int)boxedValue;
// throws exception
double unboxedValueAsDouble = (double)boxedValue;
```

yu get `InvalidCastException`. `Convert.ToDecimal` looks different:

```
return ((IConvertible)value).ToDecimal(null);
```

And that's why it works.

Comment: Good catch! A the database Price is MONEY and the percent discount was FLOAT.

Comment: @GDB don't save your upvote :), I know accepting an answer can be given to only 1, but other answers may also be helpful, so upvoting them is a way to say thanks to the answerers.